React Native (with Android Native). Unable to destroy activity (does not have a NavController)
I am facing one crash issue in my android/React Native app. Below is firebase logs.
here how I am able to reproduce it: I was able to consistently get
this to happen by

Opening an app.
Background the app.
Open the app's settings and revoke a permission
(e.g. location, notifictaion).
Try to restore the app from the
minimise state.  The crash happens every single time.

1. here is my MainActivity onCreate:
    reactRootView = ReactRootView(this)
    val packages: ArrayList<ReactPackage> = PackageList(application).packages
    packages.add(MYReactPackage())
    reactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
        .setApplication(application)
        .setCurrentActivity(this)
        .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
        .setJSMainModulePath("index")
        .addPackages(packages)
        .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
        .build()

Here onDestory:
 override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    reactInstanceManager.onHostDestroy(this)
    reactRootView.unmountReactApplication()
}

Crash on Firebase:
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView{37afbb7 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2058 #7f0a03b1 app:id/nav_host_fragment} does not have a NavController set
       at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.kt:71)
       at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onDestroyView(NavHostFragment.kt:310)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:3358)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.destroyFragmentView(FragmentStateManager.java:788)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:344)
       at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$FragmentStateManagerOperation.complete$fragment_release(SpecialEffectsController.kt:805)
       at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$Operation.cancel(SpecialEffectsController.kt:641)
       at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController.forceCompleteAllOperations(SpecialEffectsController.kt:355)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3201)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:3152)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:346)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:258)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:283)
       at com.myapp.ui.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.kt:120)
       at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:9304)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1566)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5914)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5959)
       at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:47)
       at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:60)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleItem(TransactionExecutor.java:282)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeTransactionItems(TransactionExecutor.java:150)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:93)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2602)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8623)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
       at com.android.internal.os.ExecInit.main(ExecInit.java:50)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(RuntimeInit.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:369)
        

